# In hive, How to Convert column to row

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, unpivot

in hive, how to convert columns to row??

for example

(As - is)

| index | name | sku1_nm | sku1_cnt | sku2_cnt | sku2_cnt | sku3_nm | sku3_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dgpark | box | 3 | drink | 2 | choco | 3 |

(To - be)

| index | name | sku_nm | sku_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dgpark | box | 3 |
| 1 | dgpark | drink | 2 |
| 1 | dgpark | choco | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Use union all + aggregation:

```
with mytable as(--demo dataset. Use your table instead
select                              
1 index, 'dgpark' name, 'box' sku1_nm,  3 sku1_cnt, 'drink' sku2_nm, 2 sku2_cnt, 'choco' sku3_nm, 3 sku3_cnt
)

select index, name, sku_nm, sum(sku_cnt) sku_cnt
from
(
select index, name, sku1_nm as sku_nm, sku1_cnt as sku_cnt from mytable union all
select index, name, sku2_nm as sku_nm, sku2_cnt as sku_cnt from mytable union all
select index, name, sku3_nm as sku_nm, sku3_cnt as sku_cnt from mytable
) u
group by index, name, sku_nm;
```

Result:

```
index   name    sku_nm  sku_cnt
1       dgpark  box     3
1       dgpark  choco   3
1       dgpark  drink   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function.

```
select
    a.index, a.name, split(sku, '-')[0] as sku_nm, split(sku, '-')[0] as sku_cnt
from
(
    select index, name, 
        concat_ws(',', concat(sku1_nm, '-', sku1_cnt), concat(sku2_nm, '-', sku1_cnt), concat(sku3_nm, '-', sku3_cnt)) as skus
    from temp
) a
lateral view explode(split(attr,',')) b as sku
```